# C++ Constructor problems // Inherited class

Tags: c++

Initial problem solved. (which was a redefinition error)

Furthermore, I don't know how to create a Student constructor which delivers the following:

This is how I want my program / constructors to work:

```
//main.cpp
Student s1(4015885);
s1.print();
Student s2("Test", "Student", 22, 5051022);
s2.print();
```

The output should be as follows:

```
Standart
Name
18
4015885

Test
Student
22
5051022
```

s1 works, but s2 doesn't work, because I don't have a fitting constructor

This is my Person.h

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Person {

public:
    Person(string name = "Standard", string surname =  "Name", int age**strong text** = 18);                              

    //GET
    //SET
    void print();

protected:
    string name, surname;
    int age;
};
```

Person.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Person.h"
using namespace std;

Person::Person(string n, string s, int a) : name(n), surname(s), age(a)
{
    cout << "Person constructor" << endl;
}
void Person::print() {
    cout << name << endl << surname << endl << age << endl << endl;
}
```

Student.h

```
#pragma once
//#ifndef PERSON_H
//#define PERSON_H
#include "Person.h"

class Student : public Person {
public:

    Student(int matrikel_nummer);

    int get_matriculation_number();

    void set_matriculation_number(int matriculation_number) {
        this->matriculation_number = matriculation_number;
    }

    void print();

private:
    int matriculation_number;

};
//#endif
```

Student.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Student.h"
using namespace std;

Student::Student(int matrikel_nummer) : Person(name, surname, age)

{
    cout << "Student constructor" << endl;
    this->matriculation_number = matriculation_number;
}

void Student::print() {
    cout << name << endl
            << surname << endl
            << age << endl 
            << matriculation_number << endl << endl;
}
```

Comment: Not related to your initial question but calling the base creator like:

`Person(name, surname, age)`

means trouble (if it even compiles). You are accessing protected members of the base class which are not fully initialized at the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Student.h` you have

```
Student(int matriculation_number) : Person(name, surname, age){};
```

Which declares and defines a constructor for `Student`.  Then in `Student.cpp` you have

```
Student::Student(int matrikel_nummer) : Person(vorname, nachname, alter)

{
    cout << "Student constructor" << endl;
    this->matrikel_nummer = matrikel_nummer;
}
```

Which redefines the same constructor.

You either need to get rid of the constructor definition in the class

```
Student(int matriculation_number) : Person(name, surname, age){};
//becomes
Student(int matriculation_number);
```

or get rid of the constructor in the cpp file.

Also `name, surname, age, vorname, nachname, alter` do not appear anywhere in the code you have provided.  This will not compile unless they declared somewhere else.

EDIT:

From the comments it looks like your `Student` constructor should be

```
Student(string n, string s, int a, int mn) : Person(n, s, a), matriculation_number(mn) {}
```

And you can put that in the header and you do not need a constructor definition in the cpp file.

Comment: vorname, nachname and alter are name, surname and age respectively. I was translating it all from german into english and forgot these. It should recognize name, surname and age though, since i'm including "Person.h", shouldn't it? 
I now removed the brckets {} from the consctructor in my Student.h, but now I get an unexpected token error. It looks like this:
    Student(int matriculation_number) : Person(name, surname, age);

Comment: @TonicGin I edited the answer to show how you would declare the constructor in the header file.  As far as the variables names you are not able to use them as the are class member variables.  You are going to have to have `Student` take in the strings that you will need to create the person object.

Comment: I've done that now. The initial error is gone now. Thanks so far! How do I create a Student constructor which creates a Student object as follows?
Student s1(name, surname, age, matriculation_number);

Comment: @TonicGin I have added that to the answer.

Comment: @TonicGin No problem.  If this or any other answer here helps you, you might want to consider accepting it.  I am not asking you to accept this one I am just pointing it out.

Comment: I've done that. I was looking to up your reputation but I didn't notice the check.

Answer (score 2):

Your error is here:

```
Student(int matriculation_number) : Person(name, surname, age){};
```

Remove the `{}` and the base ctor call:

```
Student(int matriculation_number);
```

Answer (score 0):

You already defined the constructor body of student:

```
Student(int matriculation_number) : Person(name, surname, age){};
```

That is already a complete implementation of the constructor body, you should write this in the header:

```
Student(int matriculation_number);
```